# Why is Bootstrap 3 not showing my labels to the left of the inputs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I would expect the following HTML to show a UI like this

Label [Input]

Label [Input]

But it is showing the labels above the inputs at all resolutions. Can anyone tell me why?

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: According bootstrap documentation all textual <input>, <textarea>, and <select> elements with .form-control are set to width: 100%  so there is no place for the labels and so they are shown above. As you know you need to use the grid system to get the result you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify label width and input tye's width

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </form>
```

Expand snippet to see in large display

Comment: That's great, thanks! I'm trying to place my controls inside my `label` so I don't have to give everything an id. Problem is the vertical space between controls is bigger, and the inputs aren't occupying the full width as per your example. Do you have any ideas why? (Code link to follow)

Answer (score 0):

This is the base of what you are looking for.

```
<form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
```